# cannot convert from String to HashMap Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, application.properties

I have below code and issue. I am running a Spring boot application to test application.properties file usage.

application.properties file,

```
server.port=8080
server.servlet.context-path=/HelloWorldBoot

myMap={key1:'value1',key2:'value2'}
```

Controller code below,

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Value("#{${myMap}}")  
    private HashMap<String,String> myMapUsingValue;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        System.out.println("myMapUsingValue : "+myMapUsingValue);

        HashMap<String, String> myMapUsingEnv = env.getProperty("myMap", HashMap.class);
        System.out.println("myMapUsingEnv : "+myMapUsingEnv);

        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Now when I hit the URL: http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldBoot/hello

Map details using @Value gets printed successfully,

```
myMapUsingValue : {key1=value1, key2=value2}
```

But I get error like below while accessing the same Map using Environment API,

```
No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.HashMap<?, ?>]]
```

How can I resolve this? How can I read the Map directly from application properties file using the Environment variable API?

Any help is appreciated on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `myMap` will be loaded as a String not a map

Comment: Try using the interface `Map` not the implementation `HashMap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables are always strings.  The fact that the Spring value injector knows how to convert them to a map is super nice, but when using the java environment api you are going to have to parse that string yourself and convert it into a Map.

Something like Jackson might make this easier.  Otherwise you might write a utility method that does this.  You might look in the spring source.

Comment: Thanks for the details. It seems that there is no straight cut way to get a map out of environment API. I had to take that string, then remove curly braces, then remove apostrophe sign and then split the string to fetch out key-value pairs and then put them in map. Whoo... Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Don't think too much just check your pojo class. 
Getting value from database is different , field from pojo class is different.